# MySQL Foreign key with NULL values

Tags: python, mysql, foreign-keys

While creating foreign key tables I was expecting foreign key values to be integer type since foreign key references pk values which are integer type.
Could you tell me if it is normal behavior and how to get integer type for foreign key values ?

```
def con_engine():
    url = "mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@localhost"
    engine = create_engine(url.format(user='root', password=''))
    engine.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS data_immo")
    return


def create_table(d_fr, nam, typ, p_k):
    url = "mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@localhost/{db}"
    engine = create_engine(url.format(user='root', password='Fer458it', db='data_immo'))
    d_fr.to_sql(name=nam, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype=typ)
    engine.execute(f"ALTER TABLE {name} ADD COLUMN {p_k} INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY")
    return


d = {'df_Bien_Immo': [df_Bien_Immo, 'Bien_Immo', d_b_i, 'Id'],
     'df_Lot': [df_Lot, 'Lot', d_l, 'Id'],
     'df_Cadastre': [df_Cadastre, 'Cadastre', d_c, 'Id'],
     'df_Mutation': [df_Mutation, 'Mutation', d_c, 'Id'],
     'df_Lot_Adr_Voie': [df_Lot_Adr_Voie, 'Lot_Adr_Voie', d_l_a_v, 'Id'],
     'df_Lot_Adr_Commune': [df_Lot_Adr_Commune, 'Lot_Adr_Commune', d_l_a_c, 'Id'],
     'df_Lot_Adr_Dpt': [df_Lot_Adr_Dpt, 'Lot_Adr_Dpt', d_l_a_d, 'Id']}
con_engine()

for key in d:
    df = d[key][0]
    name = d[key][1]
    d_type = d[key][2]
    p_key = d[key][3]
    create_table(df, name, d_type, p_key)
d_fk = {'Bien_Immo': ['fk_Id_Lot', 'Lot', 'Id'],
        'Lot': [['fk_Id_Bien', 'Bien_Immo', 'Id'],
                ['fk_Id_Cad', 'Cadastre', 'Id'],
                ['fk_Id_mut', 'Mutation', 'Id'],
                ['fk_Id_Voie', 'Lot_Adr_Voie', 'Id']],
        'Cadastre': ['fk_Id_Lot', 'Lot', 'Id'],
        'Mutation': ['fk_Id_Lot', 'Lot', 'Id'],
        'Lot_Adr_Voie': [['fk_Id_Lot', 'Lot', 'Id'],
                         ['fk_Id_Com', 'Lot_Adr_Commune', 'Id']],
        'Lot_Adr_Commune': [['fk_Id_Voie', 'Lot_Adr_Voie', 'Id'],
                            ['fk_Id_Dep', 'Lot_Adr_Dpt', 'Id']],
        'Lot_Adr_Dpt': ['fk_Id_Com', 'Lot_Adr_Commune', 'Id']}


def create_fk(name1, name2, name3, name4):
    url = "mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@localhost/{db}"
    engine = create_engine(url.format(user='root', password='Fer458it', db='data_immo'))
    engine.execute(f"ALTER TABLE {name1} ADD COLUMN {name2} int, ADD FOREIGN KEY ({name2}) REFERENCES {name3}({name4}) ON DELETE CASCADE")
    return


for key in d_fk.keys():
    if isinstance(d_fk[key][0], list):
        for i in range(len(d_fk[key])):
            [n2, n3, n4] = [d_fk[key][i][0], d_fk[key][i][1], d_fk[key][i][2]]
            print(f'(n2{n2}, n3{n3}, n4{n4})')
            create_fk(key, n2, n3, n4)
    else:
        [n2, n3, n4] = [d_fk[key][0], d_fk[key][1], d_fk[key][2]]
        print(f'(n2{n2}, n3{n3}, n4{n4})')
        create_fk(key, n2, n3, n4)
```

Many thanks,

Comment: An integer column may have null values, unless declared as not null. You have dumped a lot of code on us, can you pls narrow down where the problem occurs? It may be better if you left the python out of your question altogether as this is an sql question, not a python one.

Answer (score -1):

I understood that foreign key NULL values problem (since integer type values were expecting) come from that tables were created with 'index=False' option instead of 'True' statement. If no index created in tables, then referencing gets impossible and causes NULL values.

Comment: Do not post comments/facts as an answer. Either edit the question text or add a comment to it.